# R problems using table() with mdply

Tags: r, plyr

I'd like to count the occurrences of elements per row of a data frame. I'm trying to use table together with mdply to do so. On my test data this works fine.

```
library(plyr)
Data_frame_s1 <- data.frame(Gene_symbol=c("geneA","geneB","geneC"), cell1=c("state_1", "state_2" ,"unclassified"))
Data_frame_s2 <- data.frame(Gene_symbol=c("geneA","geneB","geneC"), cell2=c("state_1", "state_2", "unclassified"))
Data_frame_s3 <- data.frame(Gene_symbol=c("geneA","geneB","geneC"), cell3=c("state_2", "unclassified", "unclassified"))
Data_frame_s4 <- data.frame(Gene_symbol=c("geneA","geneB","geneC"), cell4=c("unclassified", "unclassified", "unclassified"))
temp = list(Data_frame_s1, Data_frame_s2, Data_frame_s3, Data_frame_s4)
Data_frame <- join_all(temp, by="Gene_symbol", type="full")
add_table <- function(row) {r = table(unname(unlist(row[-1])))}
Data_frame <- adply(Data_frame, 1, add_table)
Data_frame
```

This gives me

```
  Gene_symbol        cell1        cell2        cell3        cell4 state_1
1       geneA      state_1      state_1      state_2 unclassified       2
2       geneB      state_2      state_2 unclassified unclassified       0
3       geneC unclassified unclassified unclassified unclassified       0
  state_2 unclassified
1       1            1
2       2            2
3       0            4
```

as desired.

When I do the same on my real data, however, I get an error:

```
Error in list_to_dataframe(res, attr(.data, "split_labels"), .id, id_as_factor) : 
  Results do not have equal lengths
Calls: adply -> ldply -> list_to_dataframe
Execution halted
```

The strange thing is that I can work around this by saving my data to file, loading them back and then call mdply. So

```
Data_frame <- join_all(temp, by="Gene_symbol", type="full")
write.table(Data_frame, "test.txt")
Data_frame <- read.table("test.txt", header=TRUE)
Data_frame <- adply(Data_frame, 1, add_table)
Data_frame
```

gives me the desired result for the real data.

Does anybody have an explanation for this behaviour? I know the problem will be difficult to reproduce, but as I said I am unable to reproduce it myself with any test data and it does not even persist when I save and reload the data. But maybe someone has an idea from what I have described above.

Comment: `write.table` followed by `read.table` isn't exactly idempotent; in particular it might turn strings into factors. Maybe check the difference between the two?

Comment: @baptiste:I've tried this, i.e.
write.table(Data_frame, "test.txt")
Data_frame2 <- read.table("test.txt", header=TRUE)
Data_frame==Data_frame2
This gives me an array/df with TRUE at all positions. mce